# Dynamic width for dynamic text

Tags: html, css, animation, dynamic

I have a div, **'marqueeContainer'**, that is acting as a scrolling marquee.  In this div I have another div with the id of **'marquee'**. In THIS div, I have three divs, **LineA**, **LineB** and **LineC**.  The contents of these lines will be dynamic, loaded in from a database.

I am currently using CSS animation to scroll the **'marquee'** from right to left, with it's parent **'marqueeContainer'** having a fixed width, and the overflow set to hidden.

The problem that I'm running into is that when the amount of text in each **LINE** div is quite lengthy, the text will overlap.

[INCLUDED JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/murphy1976/1yenpwmr/2/)

How do I modify the CSS so that each line stays a single line, each div stays inline with the rest and does NOT overlap, and the animation is a seamless loop, no matter the length of the text inside each **LINE** div?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="marqueeContainer">
    <div id="marquee" class="loaded">
        <span class="line" id="lineA"><span class="title">The Singer's Musical Theatre Anthology: Mezzo-Soprano/Belter, Volume 1 Book/Audio</span> - <span class="artist">Happy to Keep His Dinner Warm from "How to Succeed in Business without Really Trying" (accompaniment)</span> | <span class="album">Ruben Piirainen, piano</span></span>
        <span class="line" id="lineB"><span class="title">The Singer's Musical Theatre Anthology: Mezzo-Soprano/Belter, Volume 1 Book/Audio</span> - <span class="artist">Happy to Keep His Dinner Warm from "How to Succeed in Business without Really Trying" (accompaniment)</span> | <span class="album">Ruben Piirainen, piano</span></span>
        <span class="line" id="lineC"><span class="title">The Singer's Musical Theatre Anthology: Mezzo-Soprano/Belter, Volume 1 Book/Audio</span> - <span class="artist">Happy to Keep His Dinner Warm from "How to Succeed in Business without Really Trying" (accompaniment)</span> | <span class="album">Ruben Piirainen, piano</span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#marqueeContainer{
    width: 570px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 20px;
    left: 47px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#marquee{
    visibility:visible;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 300%;
    height: 30px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#marquee > span{
    pointer-events: none;
}

#marquee.loaded{
    -webkit-animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#marquee span.line{
    display: none;
}

#marquee.loaded span.line{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    padding-top: 6px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
    font-size: 9pt;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0% { left: -50%; }
    100% { left: -150%; }
}
@-moz-keyframes marquee {
    0% { left: -50%; }
    100% { left: -150%; }
}
@-ms-keyframes marquee {
    0% { left: -50%; }
    100% { left: -150%; }
}
@-o-keyframes marquee {
    0% { left: -50%; }
    100% { left: -150%; }
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0% { left: -50%; }
    100% { left: -150%; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `width: 100%;` in place of `width:33.33%;` to `#marquee.loaded span.line`

add `height: 100%;` in place of `height:30px;` to `#marquee`

add `height:30px;` in place of `height: 30px;` to `#marqueeContainer`

edit: not the best solution since the marquee does not execute a perfect loop due to the text elements no longer being inline.

Comment: LineA, LineB and LineC are stacked on top of each other, I am looking for these divs to stay inline with with each other.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some research, I found a potential solution:

If you are okay with using jQuery in your project, there is a jQuery plugin you can use that might help:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>
```

I sketched out an example of something similar to what you are looking for:

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXymMY)

HTML:

```
<div class="marquee">
  <span class="line" id="lineA"><span class="title">The Singer's Musical Theatre Anthology: Mezzo-Soprano/Belter, Volume 1 Book/Audio</span> - <span class="artist">Happy to Keep His Dinner Warm from "How to Succeed in Business without Really Trying" (accompaniment)</span> | <span class="album">Ruben Piirainen, piano</span></span>
  <span class="line" id="lineB"><span class="title">The Singer's Musical Theatre Anthology: Mezzo-Soprano/Belter, Volume 1 Book/Audio</span> - <span class="artist">Happy to Keep His Dinner Warm from "How to Succeed in Business without Really Trying" (accompaniment)</span> | <span class="album">Ruben Piirainen, piano</span></span>
  <span class="line" id="lineC"><span class="title">The Singer's Musical Theatre Anthology: Mezzo-Soprano/Belter, Volume 1 Book/Audio</span> - <span class="artist">Happy to Keep His Dinner Warm from "How to Succeed in Business without Really Trying" (accompaniment)</span> | <span class="album">Ruben Piirainen, piano</span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.marquee {
  width: 570px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee span.line{
    padding-top: 6px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
    font-size: 9pt;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.marquee').marquee({
    //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
    duration: 15000,
    //gap in pixels between the tickers
    gap: 50,
    //time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
    delayBeforeStart: 0,
    //'left' or 'right'
    direction: 'left',
    //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
    duplicated: true
});
```

reference: http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin

Answer (score 0):

rather than add more external code into something I wish to keep as lightweight as possible. I have decided to keep this in the **HTML** and **CSS**. The problem I was having was **BOTH** in the **CSS** and **HTML**, not just the **CSS**.  Rather than have three *(3)* spans, I consolidated everything into one *(1)* span, but repeated the content three times to ensure everything would stay on one line.

The **#marquee**'s width is set to auto. where the **span.line**'s width is set to 100%. No white-space: nowrap needed.

And so far, I have an ever expandable marquee that loops quite seamlessly by using only **HTML** and **CSS**

[HERE'S MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/murphy1976/1yenpwmr/22/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="marqueeContainer">
    <div id="marquee" class="loaded">
        <span class="line">The Singer's Musical Theatre Anthology: Mezzo-Soprano/Belter, Volume 1 Book/Audio - Diamonds Are a Girl's Best Friend from "Gentlemen Prefer Blondes" (accompaniment) | Ruben Piirainen, piano&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The Singer's Musical Theatre Anthology: Mezzo-Soprano/Belter, Volume 1 Book/Audio - Diamonds Are a Girl's Best Friend from "Gentlemen Prefer Blondes" (accompaniment) | Ruben Piirainen, piano&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The Singer's Musical Theatre Anthology: Mezzo-Soprano/Belter, Volume 1 Book/Audio - Diamonds Are a Girl's Best Friend from "Gentlemen Prefer Blondes" (accompaniment) | Ruben Piirainen, piano   </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#marqueeContainer{
    width: 570px;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 20px;
    left: 47px;
}

#marquee{
    visibility:visible;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#marquee.loaded span.line{
    -webkit-animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}

#marquee.loaded span.line{
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 6px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
    font-size: 9pt;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}


@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0% { left: -17%; }
    100% { left: -50.4%; }
}
@-moz-keyframes marquee {
    0% { left: -17%; }
    100% { left: -50.4%; }
}
@-ms-keyframes marquee {
    0% { left: -17%; }
    100% { left: -50.4%; }
}
@-o-keyframes marquee {
    0% { left: -17%; }
    100% { left: -50.4%; }
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0% { left: -17%; }
    100% { left: -50.4%; }
}
```